# Protocol that implements hashable and overloading operators

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift-protocols

I have the following structure:

```
protocol MidiPlayable : Hashable {
    var midiValue: UInt8 { get }
}

struct PercussionSound : MidiPlayable {
    let name: String 
    let type: PercussionType    
}

struct Note : Hashable, MidiPlayable {

    let pitch: Pitch
    let octave: UInt8
    let midiValue: UInt8
}
```

I want to pass around these types to my playback device as Midiplayable as i only need to know about the raw value. Additionaly they will be placed in set so Hashable is necessary and also i want to compare them so i wish to overload the operator == != < and >

I have tried two approaches (both as free functions)

```
func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    return lhs.midiValue == rhs.midiValue
}
```

results in error 'Use of undeclared type 'Self'' 
and

```
func ==(lhs: MidiPlayable, rhs: MidiPlayable) -> Bool {
    return lhs.midiValue == rhs.midiValue
}
```

results in error 'Protocol 'MidiPlayable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements'

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Sorry i have fixed it now

Comment: In this case answer your own question and mark it as correct.

Comment: No i mean i have fixed the question i still am having this error

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
protocol MidiPlayable : Hashable {
    var midiValue: UInt8 { get }
}

extension MidiPlayable {
    var hashValue : Int {
        return midiValue.hashValue
    }
}

func ==<A: MidiPlayable>(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
    return lhs.midiValue == rhs.midiValue
}

struct PercussionSound : MidiPlayable {
    let midiValue: UInt8
    let name: String
    let type: PercussionType
}

struct Note : Hashable, MidiPlayable {
    let midiValue: UInt8
    let pitch: Pitch
    let octave: UInt8
}
```

Comment: Yes that solve that compile error but produced another one, now if i delcare a propety of type MidiPlayable it complains and says Protocol MidiPlayable can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: @LukeDeFeo That's expected and unavoidable if you want to have any self relation in your type

Comment: Ok so what work arounds can i do to declare properties in terms in of these types